# Auto remove class seconds after it becomes active

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a script working so that the background image of a div switches at a certain distance from the top of the page. What I want is for it to switch back to the original after say 2 seconds.

The following removes the class 170px later:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
var fromTopPx = 2800; // distance to trigger
var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
    jQuery('#image').addClass('scrolled');
}else{
    jQuery('#image').removeClass('scrolled');
}
var fromTopPx = 2970; // distance to trigger
var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
    jQuery('#image').removeClass('scrolled');
}
});
</script>
```

but I was hoping for it to switch back automatically:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
var fromTopPx = 2800; // distance to trigger
var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
    jQuery('#neediioneimg').addClass('scrolled');
}else{
    jQuery('#neediioneimg').removeClass('scrolled');
}
setTimeout(function(){
$('.scrolled').removeClass('scrolled');
},2000);
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure about the setTimout part, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What you have should work, at least the timeout. Do you have code that *isn't* working, and a question, for instance that it doesn't work because it's inside an event handler that trigger on every scroll etc ?

Comment: yes the top code works. the second code does not. It only switches the background at 2800 and it never switches back. My question is how to get this to switch back automatically after 2 seconds instead of the second scroll height point, does that make sense?

Comment: The problem with your code is that as long as you keep scrolling, it would keep re-adding the class. Also, you do the setTimeout before anything as a class of `scrolled`, so nothing is given the event listener

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the same functionality using chained delays and queues.  This way you don't have to worry about rogue `setTimeout` functions that are missing a corresponding `clearTimeout`, and the `removeClass` is guaranteed to only occur on the DOM element you originally added the class to, because the `removeClass` action is applied to `$(this)`.

Also, this logic will continue to fire for every scrolled pixel past the `2800` pixel mark.  This is probably not what you want.  So, an easy fix would be set the operator logic to an `==` rather than `>` within your if statement (see below).  But you may want to revise how you determine how far the user has scrolled and implement the functionality in a way that only fires once.

Something like this should work for your pause/auto-remove functionality:

```
<script>
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var fromTopPx = 2800; // distance to trigger
    var scrolledFromtop = $(document).scrollTop();

    // also, I would change the > to ==, this way it only fires once.
    if(scrolledFromtop == fromTopPx){
        $('#neediioneimg').addClass('scrolled')
             .delay(2000) // pauses for n milliseconds
             .queue(function(next){ 
                 $(this).removeClass('scrolled');
                 next(); 
             });
     } 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are wanting, now with [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tajacmsc/)

```
var fromTopPx = 2800; // distance to trigger
var hasTriggered = false;

jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if((scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx) && !hasTriggered ){
        hasTriggered = true;
        jQuery('#neediioneimg').addClass('scrolled');

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.scrolled').removeClass('scrolled');
        },2000);
    }
});
```

edit: forgot to set flag to true once fired

Comment: actually, you need to change the bool state of `hasTriggered` inside the if statement in order for this to work as desired.

Comment: hmm this seems to just have the class triggered immediately on page refresh and no switching is happening over time or scroll

Comment: @Sierra I changes some of the selectors as different browsers check for scroll in different places. Also make sure to clear your cache between tests.

Comment: Since `html` and `body` are technically 2 different DOM nodes, wouldn't this duplicate the functionality during the scroll action?  I'm worried everything within `function(){...}` will fire twice, simply because of the DOM differential reference...

Comment: firefox checks `body` and chrome checks `html`, I don't think any browser fires a scroll event on both, but I'll double check.

Comment: I think you're right, but either way, doesn't jQuery's `$(document)` reference handle the cross browser functionality inherently?

Comment: @Sierra I added a fiddle showing it working in a very simple manner, hopefully that will help

Comment: @JoeLissner Thank you so much for putting that together. It works perfect in the fiddle and I don't see why it's still not working on my page. It switches when we scroll to the Toppx value but then just stays that way. The setTimeout part isn't happening, I'm not sure if that's because I'm adding it to a Wordpress page or what. Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Sierra have you made sure to clear out your cache? I don't know of any wordpress specific issues dealing with setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

So what's the question? Does this code work? Yes. Does this code work **properly**? No. It will set a new timeout many and many times while you scroll the page, it doesn't check if you're 2800px from top, or if class if set, or if another timeout is in the queue, it will just set a new timeout every pixel of scroll. You should do something like that:

```
<script>
  // did we got back if previously scrolled more than triggerDistance
  var readyToHandleScrolling = true;

  // save the timer
  var timer = undefined

  $(document).on('scroll', function(){
    // distance from top to react on
    var triggerDistance = 2800; 

    // current distance from top
    var currentDistance = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (currentDistance >= triggerDistance) {
      // ignore if we haven't get above triggerDistance yet
      if (!readyToHandleScrolling) return;

      $('#neediioneimg').addClass('scrolled');

      timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#neediioneimg').removeClass('scrolled');
      }, 2000);

      readyToHandleScrolling = false;
    } else {
      // if we got above triggerDistance
      // clear timeout
      clearTimeout(timer);

      // remove class
      $('#neediioneimg').removeClass('scrolled');

      // show we are ready to handle a new event
      readyToHandleScrolling = true;
    }
  });
</script>
```